# (SQL) Adicionar "count 0" quando não possuir registro

Tags: sql, query, lógica

Olá, estou apanhando para uma consulta no banco de dados onde preciso pegar quantos inscritos possuem cadastrados em um torneio, o problema é que eu preciso também traga os torneios que não possuem inscritos ainda... Não estou conseguindo pensar na lógica por trás disto, ou se o problema é no meu banco mesmo.

```
    select 

    torneio.nome as nome, 

    count(inscritos_torneio.id) as qtd, 

    torneio.limiteDuplas as limite, 

    torneio.descricao as descr

from 

    torneio, inscritos_torneio

where 

    torneio.finalizado <= 0 and

    torneio.id = inscritos_torneio.idTorneio

group by torneio.id;
```

Comment: Voce terá que fazer um inner join entre a tabela de torneio e inscritos_torneio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar o `left join`

```
select T.nome as nome
      ,count(I.id) as qtd
      ,T.limiteDuplas as limite
      ,T.descricao as descr
  from      torneio           T
  left join inscritos_torneio I on T.id = I.idTorneio
 where T.finalizado <= 0
 group by T.id;
```

**Editado**

Vou dar uma explicação bem básica relacionada ao seu caso, pois é muito extenso para por aqui os 3 casos mais simples que são INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN e RIGHT JOIN

Inner join: Traz todos os TORNEIOS que possuem pelo menos 1 inscrito

Left join: Traz todos os TORNEIROS mesmo os que não possuem inscritos

Você pode ver mais a fundo neste link: [Tipos de JOINs que existem](https://www.devmedia.com.br/inner-cross-left-rigth-e-full-joins/21016)

Os JOINs são praticamente todos iguais nos diversos tipos de bancos

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.
Se não for pedir demais, poderia dar uma simples explicação? Estou pegando aulas agora de Banco de dados na faculdade, e até agora só tive experiências com consultas mais "comuns".

Comment: Verifique a edição da minha resposta e de uma procurado sobre Tipos de JOIN que você entenderá rapidinho como funciona!

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado!